# What context name should be passed to Glide method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide

In order to load image when using `viewholder` and `fragment`, I don't know context object name I should pass. Below is my glide code:

```
Glide.with(activity).load(cheeses.getImageView()).fitCenter().into(mImageView);
```

Error:

```
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1555) 
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:696)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:667)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.getSupportRequestManagerFragment(RequestManagerRetriever.java:187)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.supportFragmentGet(RequestManagerRetriever.java:195)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:104)
at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:644)
at com.support.android.designlibdemo.ViewHolderClass.ViewHolder.bindToCheese(ViewHolder.java:42)
at com.support.android.designlibdemo.CheeseListFragment$1.populateViewHolder(CheeseListFragment.java:112)
at com.support.android.designlibdemo.CheeseListFragment$1.populateViewHolder(CheeseListFragment.java:93)
```

Comment: Would you unindent those logs so they're easier to read?

Comment: Thanks! Question changed and adjusted

Comment: Personally, I think this question is pared down too much (and is so short it would be put on hold if it was a new question). The overall criteria for questions is whether they will be helpful to other users, and you've removed the error that other users might be searching for. Rolling back to rev 4 might be best?

Comment: @halfer , how about the correction now?

Comment: Much better, thanks. Note though that titles should stand alone - they are not part of the first paragraph in the body. I have adjusted this. Titles should be a short summary of the problem; they are ideal as questions, but that is not mandatory.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have critical issues with `fragment` and firebase offline capabilities but i could't ask because of downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
 Glide.with(activity)
```

You are creating a new Activity, rather than getting the current activity, which is why you get that error. You should do:

```
 Glide.with(getActivity())...
```

Ideally, you would pass the Fragment context into your `RecyclerView`, and use that context in the call. The documents say:

> **public static RequestManager with(Context context)**
>
> Begin a load with
>   Glide by passing in a context. Any requests started using a context
>   will only have the application level options applied and will not be
>   started or stopped based on lifecycle events. In general, loads should
>   be started at the level the result will be used in. If the resource
>   will be used in a view in a child fragment, the load should be started
>   with with(android.app.Fragment)} using that child fragment. Similarly,
>   if the resource will be used in a view in the parent fragment, the
>   load should be started with with(android.app.Fragment) using the
>   parent fragment. In the same vein, if the resource will be used in a
>   view in an activity, the load should be started with
>   with(android.app.Activity)}.
>
> This method is appropriate for resources that will be used outside of
>   the normal fragment or activity lifecycle (For example in services, or
>   for notification thumbnails).
>
> Parameters: context - Any context, will not be retained. Returns: A
>   RequestManager for the top level application that can be used to start
>   a load.

[Source](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/index.html)

You could do:

```
public ViewHolder(View view, Context context) {
    super(view);
    mView = view;
    mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    activity = context;
}
```

Then you could use `activity`.

Comment: No `get...()` method except `getClass()` which also not working. Cannot resolve

Comment: Pass the context in via a constructor. I added another option. You need the context of the activity or fragment you are trying to display the image in.

Comment: But if i comment out the code for Glide, it populate recycler with text base data

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. I already did similar but i used Activity class

Comment: I can only cast there. I cant assign context to activity. Let me try if casting will solve the issue.

Comment: You use `getActivity()` in the activity to get the context, then pass it in.

Comment: You call `context = getActivity()` in the activity you want to display the image in then pass that context into your view holder like `new ViewHolder(view, context)`.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load on a null Context`

Comment: Dude, I don't know what to tell you. I've posted the docs and told you how to do it. Not sure what you're doing to get a null reference, but you need the context to input into Glide. It sounds like you need to debug your code and put the activity context into the Glide `.with()` method. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. Should i show you the repo link on GitHub ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139687/discussion-between-bashorun-olajide-and-blackhatsamurai).

Answer (score 2):

In the ViewHolder use getActivity, not MainActivity mainActvity;

Comment: I tried `getActivity` already but not working since the class is not an activity class and is not fragment class

Comment: better move your holder class to a class with you are post "Create a inner class" and declare this a public and static @BashorunOlajide

Comment: You don't need to do that. You just need the context.

Comment: How does that make it more readable? You can just pass the context in as a parameter to the constructor. Moving an entire class just to get a context reference doesn't do much at all, other than create more work, and actually, make it *less* readable.